# get the id value from a button in a specific table row

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a table and each table row have his own "remove" button.

Every button from each row have his own id value.

Something like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>bla<th>
      <th>hello<ht>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         data..
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" id="{{ $counter++ }}">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to get the id from this

Thats what I've tried:

```
    $('table').on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
       ... some other code....
    });
```

Now I need to get the id of this button, without changing the first line of my jquery code!

I wasn't able to do that.. Can someone help me there?

Thanks !

Comment: first of all you have typo "<th>hello<ht>" => "<th>hello</th>", and other th tags should be with closing tags

Comment: Your code should work and @barha that must be typo while posting question

Comment: sorry, I've wrote this code manually..

Comment: your code working like charm, no any issue

Comment: probably forgot to load jquery? what is the console error? https://jsfiddle.net/rv6e1fno/

Comment: Or maybe you appending table after loaded jquery with some ajax call, so there is not your table on document loading?

Comment: no my jquery works fine - I'm using some other jquery stuff before that.. thats why I'm so confused

Comment: well.. no it works... I don't know why and I haven't changed a thing... but it works right now o.o